# How to rename a directory in Mercurial and continue to track all file changes

Tags: python, mercurial

I decided to rename some directories in my home/hobby Python package (`doc` to `docs`, `test` to `tests`, `util` to `utils`) because, now that I've thought more about it, I think the new names are more appropriate. My general thinking now is that if containers are named after their contents their names should be plural nouns.

Now that I'm ready for my next `hg commit` I'm wondering how to tell Mercurial about these directory name changes. I am new to RCS software in general and have only been using Mercurial for a couple months. When I run `hg status` it shows all the the files in these directories being removed and added, so I'm afraid if I just do a `hg addremove` I will loose all the change history for the files in these directories, or at the very least the change history will become fragmented and untraceable. I've come across the `hg rename` command, but the docs only discuss its use for individual files, not directories.

After further reading in Bryan O'Sullivan's 'Definitive Guide' it appears that maybe `rename` can refer to directories.

So here's what I've decided to try:

```
hg rename --after doc docs
hg rename --after test tests
hg rename --after util utils
hg status
hg addremove
```

Can anyone tell me if this is the accepted and preferred method for renaming directories in Mercurial, and if not, how should I do it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since you've already renamed the directories, this is perfectly OK.  (It would have saved you a manual step if you'd let Mercurial rename them for you: `hg rename doc docs`, etc. instead of doing it yourself then letting Mercurial know about it).

If you don't have any other files to check in, the `hg addremove` is superfluous.  Look in the output of `hg stat` and you should only see lines beginning with 'R' (for `doc/*`, `test/*` and `util/*`) and 'A' (for `docs/*`, etc.)

Finally, don't forget to commit the changes.

**EDIT:** Forgot to say... use `hg log --follow` to track changes across the rename.

Answer (score 17):

Mercurial has no concept of directories; it treats everything (files and directories) as files.  Also, I usually never rename files or directories manually; I just use

> hg rename old-name new-name

I suggest you do that too.

Mercurial offers a rename-tracking feature, which means that mercurial can trace the complete history of a file which has been renamed. If you manually rename this, its not possible.

However, as you have already renamed them manually, you need to use the `--follow` argument along with `hg log` to track the file changes through the history.

Personally I'd just go with `hg rename` and it should be the preferred method.

Comment: Correction: Mercurial does not treat directories as files; it ignores them.  You cannot track a directory.

Answer (score 11):

One reason to use --after instead of renaming with hg is if you are using a refactoring tool that does more than just rename e.g. also fixes references.

Comment: This is a big issue, if you are not using a hg plugin for visual studio.